# Creating an associative array with strings

Tags: php, hashtable, associative-array

I read some words from a text file, storing each word as an array element using the file() function. Now I need to sort each word and create an associative array that stores the sorted strings as keys and the original strings as values like so :

`$hash_table = array( 'sorted_string' => 'original string' );`

I loop through every word read from the file and sort it in ascending order but when it comes to pushing it to the associative array, I am completely lost. Can anyone show me how to create the associative array ?

Comment: The syntax is quite simple : `$hash_table["key"] = "value";`

Comment: How do you sort a single word? Do you want the letters to be switched position to be alphabettical?

Comment: So "Correct" would be sorted as "ceorrtC" ?

Comment: @MayankKumar Please post the code you're using to generate the associative array, that way we could "fix" where you went wrong.

Comment: @HugoDelsing : Exactly. That's what I'm doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$a = array('green', 'yellow', 'red');//actual
$b = array('green', 'yellow', 'red');
sort($b); //sorted
$c = array_combine($b, $a);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, consider this:

```
$sorted;   //sorted array
$original; //original array

foreach($sorted as $key){
  $index = 0;
  $new_array[$key] = $original[$index++];
}
```

Comment: good, not sure if that's what the OP needs since this will give a multidimensional array (`$original` is an array).

Comment: @HamZa I think, the now edited answer will atleast be close to answer the OP's question.

Comment: Yeah, you got +1 from me :)

Comment: @HamZa I think you should rather +1 the other answer. :)

Comment: I did, it's a bit sad since I was going to post exactly that answer if the OP has answered my question (in the comments) :p

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want:

```
<?php
//create an array with words, similar to what you get with file()
$str = "here is a list of random words that will be sorted";
$array = explode(" ", $str);

//a place to store the result
$result = array();

//check each value
foreach($array as $word) {
  //str_split will create an array from a string
  $letters = str_split(trim($word));
  //sort the letters
  sort($letters);

  //implode the letters again to a single word
  $sorted = implode($letters);

  //add to result
  $result[$sorted] = $word;
}

//dump
var_dump($result);

//sort on the key
ksort($result);

//dump
var_dump($result);
?>
```

This will output

```
//unsorted
array(11) {
  ["eehr"]=>
  string(4) "here"
  ["is"]=>
  string(2) "is"
  ["a"]=>
  string(1) "a"
  ["ilst"]=>
  string(4) "list"
  ["fo"]=>
  string(2) "of"
  ["admnor"]=>
  string(6) "random"
  ["dorsw"]=>
  string(5) "words"
  ["ahtt"]=>
  string(4) "that"
  ["illw"]=>
  string(4) "will"
  ["be"]=>
  string(2) "be"
  ["deorst"]=>
  string(6) "sorted"
}

//sorted on key
array(11) {
  ["a"]=>
  string(1) "a"
  ["admnor"]=>
  string(6) "random"
  ["ahtt"]=>
  string(4) "that"
  ["be"]=>
  string(2) "be"
  ["deorst"]=>
  string(6) "sorted"
  ["dorsw"]=>
  string(5) "words"
  ["eehr"]=>
  string(4) "here"
  ["fo"]=>
  string(2) "of"
  ["illw"]=>
  string(4) "will"
  ["ilst"]=>
  string(4) "list"
  ["is"]=>
  string(2) "is"
}
```